# Detecting in second function if first function has returned value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one JS function that makes an ajax call and runs continuously

```
function First(ServerId)
{
    var CallServer = jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "somefile.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response)
        {
           // do something here
           First(response.ServerId);
        }
    }};
}
```

In *somefile.php* there's a sleep timer of 60 seconds, so ajax call returns response after 60 seconds. Every time a different server id is returned.

Now I have another function and I want to do something like this

```
function Second()
{
   /*
   wait for 5 seconds to see if function First() has returned server id
   if (ServerIdIsReturned)
   {
         i) abort CallServer
        ii) make another Ajax call (CallServer2)
       iii) after CallServer2 is done, call CallServer with the returned ServerId
   }
   else
   {
         i) abort CallServer
        ii) make another Ajax call (CallServer2)
       iii) after CallServer2 is done, call CallServer with the ServerId as 0
   }       
   */
}
```

I am not sure if I have explained it properly, but I want to check in function `Second()` if function `First()` has returned a new server id and accordingly proceed further. I think I'd need to use setTimeout and breakup the Second() function, but not sure.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: sidenote: It's dangerous to put the `{` on newlines, because this can cause serious bugs (try this with returning an object and you will fail horribly).

Answer (score 2):

Just call the second function in the success block of your first function.

```
 success: function(response) {
      // do something here
      First(response.ServerId);
      // proceed further
      Second();
 }
```

in order to make a delayed call just use `setTimeout(Second,5000);`

Comment: I just want to wait for 5 seconds to check if server id has returned. If I directly call `Second()` from `First()` how and where can I apply the timer ?

Comment: @Sachyn You don't need the timeout, because you included the call in the success-function. This guarantees that the server-response is present.

Comment: I do actually. When `Second()` is called, I have to wait for 5 seconds to see if `ServerId` is returned. If yes abort the existing Ajax call, make another Ajax call, and once that call is done call the earlier aborted Ajax request by passing the returned `ServerId`. Otherwise simply abort the first ajax call, make another one, and after that is done call the aborted request again by passing 0 as the `ServerId`

Comment: please check I have modified my question

Comment: I don't get it, why you want to wait 5 seconds. The moment you are entering `success` your ServerId is present. Or do you need to wait for the `First()` called in the success-function to return the next ServerId?

Comment: Right. `Second()` can be called anytime, I just don't want to lose out on getting `ServerId` if `First()` is about to complete soon. If its more than 5 sec, then I have to pass `ServerId` as 0

Answer (score 0):

set a global variable to false before the call and set it to true when the call has returned then you can just check that variable

Comment: Global var and use of Interval. This is completely unnecessary, since you have the success callback.

Comment: well its just one way of achieving the same basic effect

Comment: Yes, a global namespace polluting, ressource consuming and "not taking javasripts asynchronous nature into account" way.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the built in timeout ability of the jQuery ajax call - set your 5 second timeout and then add an error handler - check for a timeout and call again, if appropriate.

```
var CallServer = jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "somefile.php",
        timeout:5000,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response)
        {
           // do something here
           First(response.ServerId);
        },
        complete(jqXHR, textStatus)
        {
            if (textStatus === "timeout")
           {
               Second();
            }
        }
    }};
```